# An integer $n \geq 2$ is called square-positive- proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

An integer $n \geq 2$ is called square-positive if there are $n$ consecutive positive integers whose sum is a square. Determine the first four square-positive integers.

So I have found the first four square-positive numbers, but I need to prove that why it $4$ is not a square-positive number and I also need to write a general formula for determining whether a number is square-positive or not. I have tried to write the sum of consecutive positive integers like this $a + a +1 + a + 2 + a+3 \dots a - 1$ and I wrote it like this for all numbers, and part of the proof for why $4$ isn't a square-positive number is that $4a + 6$ is not divisible with $4$. But I haven't got so far.

Here is my answer:

2 : 4 + 5 = 9  which is 3^2

3 : 2 + 3 + 4 = 9 which is 3^2

5: 18 + 19 + 20 + 21 + 22 = 100  which is 10^2

6: 35 + 36 + 37 + 38 + 39 + 40 = 225  which is 15^2

Interesting fact is that for all odd numbers and some even numbers like 6 and 10, you can find out which number is the first (the one you start with and then go forward here like 3, 2, 18 and 35) using this formula :

(I show it in an example because I still can't write it algebraically):

For example: the sum of 95 subsequent numbers is 5n + 10

(10^2 - 10) /5 = 18

So your first number is 18

And if you keep adding, 18 + 19 + 20 + 21 + 22 you get 100 which is 10^2, the same number you squared.

Comment: Did you say $3+4=9$?!

Comment: Surely you mean $4+5=9$.

Comment: Yes, I can't edit it now but I meant 4+5 = 9

Comment: @NegativeCreep Edited, see if correct.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, consider the $n$ integers centered on $4n$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what tools you are supposed to use to demonstrate that 4 is not a square-positive number. I guess you can do it in different ways. Here's one:

Take four consecutive numbers.
Now take a unit from the last one and put it to the second.
The last three numbers are now equal. If you sum them all, you get: $3n + (n - 2) = 4n - 2$.

Now for reduction ad absurdum you want that expression to give you the square of an integer: $4n - 2 = x^2$ which is equivalent to: $n = ( x^2 + 2) / 4$. Now you can say that n is an integer only if $( x^2 + 2 )$ is multiple of 4, but this can be true only if x is an even number. Now the square of any even number is of the form $(2^2n *...)$ i.e. $(4^n *...)$ So it is always a multiple of 4. If $x^2$ needs to be always divisible for 4, then $(x^2 + 2)$ can never be a multiple of 4 and therefore n can never be an integer. But $n$ is of course an integer, it is the third of the four consecutive numbers chosen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple test to show that $n=4q$, where q is odd, cannot be a solution.

The sum of the first $a$ integers is:
$$\frac{a(a+1)}{2}$$
so the sum of $n$ consecutive integers starting at $a$ is:
$$\frac{(a+n)(a+n-1)}{2}-\frac{a(a-1)}{2} = \frac{n(2a+n-1)}{2}$$
since this number must be equal to a perfect square:
$$\frac{n(2a+n-1)}{2}=k^2$$
substitute $n=4q$ for some odd integer $q$:
$$2q(2a-1+4q)=k^2$$
it should be apparent that $k$ must be an even integer, therefore substitute $k=2m$:
$$2(2a-1+4q)q=4m^2$$
$$(2a-1+4q)q=2m^2$$
The numbers $2a-1+4q$ and $q$ must be odd, but the RHS must be even, therefore it is not possible for this equation to be solved over the integers, and so there is no solution for $n=4q$.

I know that this isn't a full proof, but I am still working on it

Comment: How is the generalization?
Or a method for determining whether a number is square-positive or not?

Comment: (Your expression is the sum of $n$ integers starting at $a+1$)

Comment: my bad, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

We prove the following result:

If $n=2^b \cdot d, d \text{ is odd, then } n \text{ is square-positive if and only if } b=0  \text{ or } b  \text{ is odd}$.

$\underline{\text{Case 1}}$: $b$ is even and $b>0$. Let $b=2c$. We prove by contradiction $n$ cannot be square-positive. If it were, then there exist $n$ consecutive positive integers,
$$
a, a+1, \ldots, a+n-1
$$

such that the sum of these numbers is a square, i.e.,

$$
S=a+(a+1)+\cdots + (a+n-1) = n\frac{n+2a-1}{2} =T^2
$$

for some $T\in \mathbb{N}$.

Note that $n=2^{2c}\cdot d$ is even, and
$$
T^2 = S = 2^{2c-1}\cdot d \cdot (n+2a-1),
$$

which cannot be a perfect square because 1) $d(n+2a-1)$ is odd and, 2) $2c-1$, the highest power of its factor $2$ is odd, a contradiction.

$\underline{\text{Case 2}}: b=0$. Let $n=d=2m+1$, then the sum of the following $n$ consecutive numbers is a perfect square:

$$
n-m, n-m+1, \ldots, n+m.
$$

Indeed,

$$
S = (n-m)+(n-m+1)+\cdots +(n+m) = n \cdot \frac{(n-m)+(n+m)}{2}=n^2.
$$

$\underline{\text{Case 3}}: b=2c+1 $ for some $c\geqslant 0$, then $n=2^{2c+1}d$. We show that the sum of the following $n$ consecutive numbers is a perfect square:

$$
a, a+1, \ldots, a+(n-1),
$$

where

$$
a=\frac{1+d(K^2-2^{2c+1})}{2}
$$

and $K$ is some odd positive integer such that

$$
K^2 > 2^{2c+1}.
$$

For example, if $c\geqslant 1$, we can pick $K=2^{c+1}-1$. If $c=0$, we can pick $K=3$. Also note that $a$, the first number in the sequence, is a positive integer by construction.

Finally,
$$
S=n\frac{n+2a-1}{2} = \frac{2^{2c+1}d}{2} \left[ 2^{2c+1}d + d(K^2-2^{2c+1}) \right] = 2^{2c} d [ d K^2 ] = (2^c d K)^2. \blacksquare
$$

Example: $n=8=2^3 \cdot 1, c=1, d=1, K=3 \Rightarrow a=1$, and the sum of the sequence is $1+2+\cdots+8=36=6^2$.

Comment: Note that I could combine the case of $c=0$ and $c \ge 1$ by having

$2^{2c+1}\cdot d+2a-1=d(2^{c+2}-1)^2$, or

$2^{2c+1}\cdot d+2a-1=d\cdot K^2$, $K$ is any odd number such that $2^{2c+1}\cdot d<d\cdot K^2$

Comment: Thank you! But I don't quite understand how you got to the conclusion, could you simplify your proof? Sorry,  if I'm being stupid I'm not used to solving this type of problem.

Comment: I just don't get it, how do you know what the sequent can be if you have an odd or an even n?

Comment: And what happens in the 5th line?

Comment: where does 2a - 1 come from?

Comment: I simplified my proof. Please let me know if you have further questions. The idea to to find $a$, the first of the sequence so that the sum is a perfect square. When $b$ is even and not zero there's no solution. When $b$ is odd I gave you a solution for $a$ (which is not unique because there can be infinitely many $K$).

Comment: Yes I understand the logic and I understand your conclusion but I don't follow what you did after ... "we will see if we can find a solution." You suddenly start multiplying d and then 2a-1 comes up I'm so confused...

Comment: I meant if we can find an $a$ which makes the sum a perfect square. I am multiplying to make the sum a perfect square. Since $2^{2c}$ is already a square, if we make $d(2^{2c+1}d+2a-1)$ another square then we are done. Right? Of course there are many ways to do this, but one way is to make $2^{2c+1}d+2a-1=dK^2$ for some K, then we will have $d\cdot dK^2=(dK)^2$.

Comment: I made another edit. Sorry I should've written more clearly.

Comment: I'm just a 9th grader, I literally don't understand why your proof is so complicated. I basically don't understand anything after "we will see if we can find an  which makes  a perfect square." Sorry... I'm being stupid haha

Comment: I just learned how to format better and improved my logic. Hopefully you can understand now. Please take a look.

Comment: I think that you are making this too complicated, for example, I never understand where you get n^2c*d from, what your variables represent, or what you mean with this operation ^2==2^2−1⋅⋅(+2−1). By that, I don't mean that your logic or your solution is wrong it's that you are doing several operations, to write a simple proof and you don't explain what you are doing which makes this really really confusing for me. But again, I'm not used to high-level- math-kind-of-proof. So it might be my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b-2, b-1, b, b+1$ be four consecutive numbers. The sum is $4b -2$.  Let $m^2 = 4b-2$  Then $\frac {m^2}2 = 2b-1$.  And $2|m^2$.  So $2|m$.  Let $m=2k$ then $4k^2 = 4b -1$ and $2k^2 = 2b-1$.  That's impossible as the LHS is even and the RHS is odd.  So $4$ is not square positive.

=====

In general:

........

If the first integer is $a$ and there are $n$ consecutive integers the numbers are $a, a+ 1,......, a+(n-1)$ and the sum of the the integers is $a + (a+ 1) + ..... + (a + (n-1)) = n\cdot a + (1+ 2 + ...... + (n-1)) = n\cdot a + \frac {(n-1)n}2$.

If $n\cdot a + \frac {(n-1)n}2 = M^2$ then by completing the square

$\frac 12n^2 - (a-\frac 12)n -M^2 = 0$ and .....

well, we *can* keep going but.... let's try to be clever....

If $n=2k+1$ is an odd number and the *middle* number is $b$ then the first number is $b-k$ and the last number is $b+k$ and the sum of the number is $$(b-k) + (b-k+1) + ..... + (b-1) + b+ (b+1) + ..... + (b+k) =\\ nb + (-k+(-k+1)+...... + (-1) + 0 + 1 + 2 + ..... k) =\\nb + 0= nb$$.  ANd $nb$ can be square positive whenever $b= n$.  (and other times).  For intsance.  $1=1^2$ and $2+3+4=3^2$ and $3+4+5+6+7 = 5^2$ and $(n-\frac {n-1}2) + ...... + (n + \frac {n-1}2) = n^2$.

So all odd numbers are square positive.

And if $n= 2k$ is even the there is no middle number but if the "middlish" number (off by one half) is $b$:Then we can notice that first $k$ of these numbers are $b-k ,b-(k-1) , b-(k-2),........, b-1$; and the second $k$ of these numbers are $b, b+1, b+2, ......, b+(k-1)$; and the sum of these numbers are $$nb + (-k,-(k-1),-(k-2),......., (k-2),(k-1)) =\\ nb - k =\\ 2kb -k = k(2b-1)$$.  And that can be a square positive every time we have $2b-1 = k=\frac n2$.

But this is possible only if  $\frac n2$ is odd.

But if $k=2m$ is even we must have $2m(2b-1)$ is a perfect square which requires $m$ to be even.

By induction will prove $n$ is square positive if and only if $n = 2^{odd}\cdot odd$.

So the list of *all* square positive numbers are $2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,21,22,32,24,......$ etc.

Comment: how can n= 2k ever be odd?

Comment: "how can n= 2k ever be odd?"  Um... it can't?  I considered two case $n=2k+1$ being odd, and $n=2k$ being even....  Of course if $n-2k$ is even $\frac n2$ can be either even or odd.

Comment: sorry I don't really understand what you did after "number is + and the sum of the number is..." You have written two different sums that are equal to nb?

Comment: Stupid mathjax formatting.  It's *one* sum but it's split over two lines and has text written in the middle of it.